# I tried creating EMR thru terraform. and got this error

Tags: amazon-emr

I tried creating EMR thru terraform. and got this error. Can someone help me how to resolve this issue
Error: Error waiting for EMR Cluster state to be "WAITING" or "RUNNING": TERMINATING: : An EC2 ClientInternalError has occurred. For more information, see https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-client-internal-error.